# Create Array from data in the OPTIONS table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, sql, options

Good Day everyone,

I'm trying to create an array from data in the Options table of wordpress.

My data all start the same way *plugin_order_* and then name of the field information.

Is there a way to extract all those data and create an array with WordPress command?

Or the only way would be to do it with a proper "SQL Query" which I think many people say not to do in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$all_options = wp_load_alloptions();
$plugin_order_options = array();
foreach( $all_options as $name => $value ) {
    if(stristr($name, 'plugin_order_')) $plugin_order_options[$name] = $value;
}
print_r($plugin_order_options);
```

In plain English:

> We load all WP options in `$all_options`. We copy options from `$all_options` to `$plugin_order_options` if their name contains `plugin_order_`. We print `$plugin_order_options`. We scratch our head, unhappy with the size of the customized mono-spaced font of our browser. We should have left it default.

As mentioned by @Rarst, `wp_autoload_options()` will retrieve all autoload options or all options, if no autoloaded ones exist. So, if the above code doesn't work for you, you might want to try this one:

```
$options = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options ORDER BY option_name" );

foreach ( (array) $options as $option ) :
    if ( $option->option_name == '' )
        continue;
    $name = esc_attr( $option->option_name );
    if(stristr($name, 'plugin_order_'))
        $plugin_order_options[$name] = is_serialized( $option->option_value ) ? 
            maybe_unserialize( $option->option_value ) :
            $option->option_value;
endforeach;

print_r($plugin_order_options);
```

It basically fetches all entries from `wp_options` table, and for those who have `plugin_order_` in their name it passes the value to our `$plugin_order_options` array. This time I also check if data is serialized and attempt to unserialize it.

Comment: As usual Thanks Andrei, I will look into that and come back to you!

Comment: Please don't just dump code, [edit] your answer and add some detail how this bit of code may help solve the issue

Comment: The code is self explanatory, especially since the variable names are descriptive. Have you read the question before criticizing? It asks for a method to obtain an array. There's no debate, no discussion.

Comment: So many people on this board are just trying to complain about what people answers. I asked the question, he gave me the code, and it was clear enough that I didn't had to complain... Choooo Trolls Chooooo

Comment: Please note that the standards of this site isn't just to "give you code", it's to collect good answers which will be valuable long term to _many_ people. Also the "self explanatory" code is actually not in this case. Despite its name [`wp_load_alloptions()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_load_alloptions/) will **not** retrieve **all** options in typical case, but only those that are set to autoload. It might have worked for you, but it's not a completely valid answer for general case.

Comment: I actually didn't know that, @Rarst, because every time I needed wp options the ol' deprecated `get_alloptions()` got them for me. Thank you for making me look closer into this and come up with a solution that will probably be valuable in the long term, to *many people*.